# how can i switch from normal WPF UI to Modern UI in my Silverlight business application?

Tags: c#, silverlight, modern-ui

I want to create a Silverlight business application, instead of using normal WPF i want to use  a Modern UI. I want my project to use mui ModernWindow page navigation. how do i switch from normal WPF User interface to Modern User Interface look and feel?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I get a Modern UI look and feel in a Silveright App?

It may sound obvious, but just replicate what you want and put it in! The tiles in Modern UI are just special data templates (easily used in Silverlight).

As far as the re-ordering and insertion animations (among others), those are part of the Modern UI framework and are not so easily replicated. If the source is out there, I'm not aware of where it is.

So the answer is, unfortunately, that you have to re-make anything you want from Modern UI.

This sample has the "tile" templates found in the Bing apps: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-ListView-and-GridView-6bd77f71